# projective space, quotient map, existence of a function

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}P^2\to\mathbb{R}P^2$ continuous. Let $q:S^2\to\mathbb{R}P^2$ denote the quotient map.
>
> Show: It exists a function $h: S^2\to S^2$ with $q\circ h=g\circ q$

Hello,

I really struggle with the tasks I get lately, and again I have no clue here, which is kinda embarassing.
Could you maybe give me a hint, or direction how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ $\mathbb{S^2}$ is the universal cover of $\mathbb{R}P^2$, so it suffices to show that the map $g \circ q:\mathbb{S^2}\to \mathbb{R}P^2$ has a lift with respect to the covering map $q$. Note that $\pi_1(\mathbb{S^2})=0$.

Comment: Is it easy to show that $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^2)=0$. We do not have this result yet.

Comment: Well it depends upon what you've learned. See Hatcher or Munkres for a proof of this.

Comment: Is there not an other way, to show this?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I don't think so. What's the source?

Comment: It is a current homework, and I can not imagine that we have to show $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^2)=0$ on our own. We showed that for a covering space $p:Y\to X$, $X$ hausdorff, $f:Z\to X$ continuous, $Z$ path connected and locally path connected with f(z)=x=p(y) it exists a continuous function $\tilde{f}:Z\to Y$ with $p\circ \tilde{f}=f$ and $\tilde{f}(z)=y$ is equivalent to $f_{\ast}\pi_1(Z,z)\subseteq p_{\ast}\pi_1(Y,y)$ in $\pi_1(X,x)$.

Comment: This is to show $\pi_1(S^2)=0$, right? Why is it suffices to show that the map $g\circ p:S^2\to\mathbb{R}P^2$ has a lift? We did not show that either. Excuse me. It is hard, when you do not know what we can use. I am sorry.

Comment: Look at the definition of a lift, if the lift is $h$, then you have $p\circ h=g\circ p$.

Comment: Oh, you are right... Therefore I need to give this lift $h$ now.

Comment: Yes, and the existence of $h$ is a given because of the lemma that you stated.

Comment: @Hmm: It is not true that a continuous map $f$ from $S^1$ to $S^2$ is not surjective. Indeed, using space-filling curves, it is easy to construct surjective continuous maps $f$ from $S^1$ to $S^2$! What _is_ true, is that there is a nonsurjective continuous map $g\colon S^1\rightarrow S^2$ homotopic to $f$. So that you may _assume_ $f$ nonsurjective, and continue your argument.

Comment: @JohannesHuisman, that's why I said not-so-precise. However I might have been a bit wrong in my wording, so I'll change that.